# Application.Run(new Form1) method and using list missing

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VB 2010 express to create a simple forms application, no problem when I run it but why didn't I have to type the Application.Run() method to get it to work as I did in the past and why is this missing?

I've checked the show all files in solution explorer.

Also my form code doesn't list the usual using namespaces at the top of the code either!

Comment: Project + Properties, Application tab.  Note the checked "Enable application framework" setting.  The application framework takes care of the Application.Run() call.